# Downgrade bluez to version 4

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez

I've got Nokia BH-105 headset, that I want to use with my PC.

I can pair, but cannot connect to BH-105:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 00:1C:EF:CA:B3:D0
Attempting to connect to 00:1C:EF:CA:B3:D0
[CHG] Device 00:1C:EF:CA:B3:D0 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 00:1C:EF:CA:B3:D0 Connected: no
```

[Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Tested_headsets) states, that BH-104 is tested to work with bluez4. It seems to me that both BH-104 and BH-105 are similar devices.

As far as I understand HFP/HSP are not supported by bluez5 anymore. At the same time BH-105 does not support A2DP. HFP/HSP are supported by bluez4.

I tried to install earlier version of bluez, but it cannot be found:

```
qeeet@qeeet-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install bluez=4.99-2
E: Version '4.99-2' for 'bluez' was not found
```

How do I downgrade bluez to any 4.x version?

UPDATE:

I did everything as described here https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates and it doesn't work. I get this message:

```
qeeet@qeeet-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[lots_of_text]
Reading package lists... Done
qeeet@qeeet-PC:~$ sudo apt-get -t wheezy install bluez
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'wheezy' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Comment: This version of bluez is only available for wheezy.  <https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/bluez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add these lines to sources as well (wasn't mentioned in debian wiki):

```
deb     http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

Queet,
duplicate your apt jessy source in your sources.list but change jessy to wheezy.
then run apt-get update.
for safety list the available bluez versions with "apt-cache showpkg bluez" without "" the last printed values is the versions copy the version name then enter the following "sudo apt-get -t wheezy install bluez=(copied version name)"
Hope it works for you.